# Android GCM app working on emulator but not on real devices

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing a chatting application, it consists of two android applications one is server app and client app, but only server app sends the data and client app receives it.I have tested it on emulator everything is working fine but, when it is tested on real devices the server app is sending the message successfully(am getting a response `Result: [ messageId= 0:1425659852679944%ec35664638eb0007 ]` from server app), but their is no notification on client app.

NOTE: There is no back end server or sql database, for now am just copying the client app's registration id and giving to server app to which the message should be sent.

please help to solve this, thanks in advance

**my client app's manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.democlientapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.democlientapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.democlientapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>



        <activity
            android:name="com.democlientapp.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.democlientapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.democlientapp.GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My client app's BroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.democlientapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("tag", "GcmBroadcastReceiver.java ok");
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }


}
```

**Client app's GcmIntentservice.java**

```
package com.democlientapp;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static  int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    String TAG="tag";
    SharedPreferences sp;
    StringBuffer sb;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String extras1 = intent.getExtras().getString("data");
        Log.i("tag", "string extras :"+extras1);
        Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
        Log.i("tag", "bundle extras :"+extras.toString());

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras);

            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.i("tag","GcmBroadcastReceiver.java send notification");


        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Spy notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        //mNotificationManager.no
        //NOTIFICATION_ID++;
    }
}
```

**My server app's code to send messages to google server**

```
package com.application.service;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

public class ServerMsgs extends IntentService{

    public ServerMsgs() {
        super(ServerMsgs.class.getSimpleName());
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



String msg1;
SharedPreferences sp;

 static String API="AIzaSyA9G-pzEqVIT7am5IF9p_y0on0J_ViAwk";    


public String getTargetRegid(){
    String  name="MyPrefs";
     sp = this.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String prefName = sp.getString("CLIENTUSERNAME", "false");
    Log.i("tag","server.java, client regid is:  "+prefName);
    //String status="false";
    return prefName;


}


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent in) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         msg1=(String) in.getExtras().get("msg");



        try {
            //Please add here your project API key: "Key for browser apps (with referers)".
            //If you added "API key Key for server apps (with IP locking)" or "Key for Android apps (with certificates)" here
            //then you may get error responses.
            Sender sender = new  Sender(API);

            // use this to send message with payload data
            Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .collapseKey("message")
            .timeToLive(45)
            .delayWhileIdle(false)
            .addData(msg1, "") //you can get this message on client side app
            .build();  
            Log.i("tag", "server.java final message : "+message);

            //Use this code to send notification message to a single device
            //Result result = sender.send(message, getTargetRegid(),  1);
            Result result = sender.send(message,"APA91bF9VefxfRnAH_v20BMSNAhSUpqt2L5PbQYk2KhIiEniX5emx7SRsgcmFNGK4BPddLf99kxVr6Y8iopAh-apxcD46UEU8OJFnD3WsCKNZcIYAbGa5e3KM8SXG-3i8A02rCoOLgxGt-iW9TmZqtWzOiQovjbuIQ",  1);

            //System.out.println("Message Result: "+result.toString()); 
            Log.i("tag", "Message Result: "+result.toString());






        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: We might need to see the IntentService you created, but is the device registering with GCM properly? Are you getting any activity out of the GcmBroadcastReceiver?

Comment: please check it i have added Intentservice code, the device is registering successfully. There is no activity out of GcmBroadcastReceiver on real devices, but working fine on emulator....please help me to figure this problem out. Thank you

Comment: Do you have the registration ID of the client saved on the server side to send messages to?

Comment: client app will give me registration id and just coping the ID and using it in the server app to send messages (here both client and server apps are installed on same phone)

Comment: Can you post the code where you're sending the GCM message?

Comment: please check it i have added the code

Comment: The client app is working fine on android 4.2.2v but not on 2.3.6v i think there is problem with GCMBroadcasteReceiver.

Comment: What you are doing does not seem right. Have you read through the [GCM Server tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html)? Also you hard coded the registration I'd instead of calling the getTargetRegid() function. Registration IDs are not guaranteed to be permanent.

Comment: I think I see the problem though. The com.google.android.gcm.server package has been deprecated. You'll have to read through the link I posted and implement that kind of server.

Comment: for now am just giving directly the registration id. Today I have tested both  my client app and server app on real  android device (4.2.2 v) both worked perfectly, but the problem now is the client app's GCMBroadcastReceiver is not firing on android 2.3.6 version devices, please help me